# Is it wrong to normalise Respiration Rate to compare between individuals?

Tags: anova, normalization

I conducted an experiment where some participants were subjected to high levels of CO2 for 11 consecutive amounts of time. Some were controls "C" that had no CO2 but thought they did and the rest "N" were actually subjected to high CO2.

A boxplot of their respiration rate over time looks like this:
[image]

Normalising the respiration rate between [0,1] for each individual by:
$$X=\frac{x-min(x_i)}{max(x_i)-min(x_i)}$$

yields the following boxplot that shows a stronger difference between time-segments:[image]

Is it wrong to normalise by max and min of each person to compare between groups?

**ANOVA show different p values but still show significance between groups.**